# Is there an environment variable to disable PyMunk/Chipmunk from printing `Loading chipmunk for Linux`

Tags: python, chipmunk, pymunk

I am trying to run a PyMunk simulation in a subprocess and get a floating point return value from a pipe, however every time I run the simulation I also get stuck with a `Loading chipmunk for Linux (64bit) [/home/user/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pymunk/libchipmunk.so` message.

I have already disabled the PyGame loading message with an `os.environ['PYGAME_HIDE_SUPPORT_PROMPT'] = '1'`, however I can't find documentation for a similar variable in PyMunk.

I'd like to avoid writing files with the output I require, as its only a single float that I need to get.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works on Windows, i think it should work also on Linux.
From the documentation:
To change make sure you import pymunk before any sub-packages and then set the option you want.
http://www.pymunk.org/en/latest/pymunkoptions.html

```
import pymunkoptions
pymunkoptions.options["debug"] = False
import pymunk
```

So make sure you set the options before any other import.

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu on Windows.  Doesn't seem to have any effect.